# Run Go app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, go

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at https://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku. Initially everything seems to work:

```
ceiroa-ltm:my_heroku_app ceiroa$ heroku create -b https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git
Creating glacial-badlands-6720... done, stack is cedar-14
BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git
https://glacial-badlands-6720.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/glacial-badlands-6720.git
Git remote heroku added
ceiroa-ltm:my_heroku_app ceiroa$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 925 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Installing go1.3.3... done
remote: -----> Running: godep go install -tags heroku ./...
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 1.5MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v4
remote:        https://glacial-badlands-6720.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/glacial-badlands-6720.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

However, no dynos are spinned:

```
ceiroa-ltm:my_heroku_app ceiroa$ heroku ps
ceiroa-ltm:my_heroku_app ceiroa$
```

And the app gives an error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Following the instructions at https://github.com/kr/go-heroku-example does work. So maybe it's the Eclipse IDE folder structure that is breaking things?

Comment: There's hope. I currently have a Go app running on Heroku (plug: www.weberc2.com). I think you might be able to get some logs from heroku that give more detail about the error. My hunch is that your Procfile isn't set up correctly; could you post more details about your project?

Comment: Thanks for pitching in, @weberc2. Good to hear you can successfully run a Go app on Heroku. I'm actually interested in knowing how stable in the long term the Go support will be. Regarding the procfile, I think it was correct, as I was able to set up another app with the same one, as mentioned below.

Comment: Ah, i didn't notice that you answered your own question. I thought that was a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bunch of things that didn't work:

1. downgrade go version (to match the one defined in https://github.com/kr/go-heroku-example/blob/master/Godeps/Godeps.json)
2. move from default Eclipse Go structure to one without src, bin, or pkg inside project
3. use hyphens instead of underscores (for project name and in Procfile and Godeps.json)
4. define full identifier in Godeps.json

At the end and started from scratch again, creating the project from the command line instead of from Eclipse, and this worked.

From the things above, I can rule out #1 and #4 as fixes, as I'm back to using the same config I initially had.

Another thing that was throwing me off was references to ".godir" in different websites and posts. I don't know what this file used to be used for, but it doesn't seem necessary any more.

I'm going to point to Eclipse and its Go plugin as the culprits, for now.

Comment: I can testify to the command-line story; not sure what eclipse is doing, but it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku now officially supports [Go](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/7/7/go_support_now_official_on_heroku) and has a [Getting Started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#introduction) guide.